# Active threads in WebSphere 8.5

Tags: python, websphere, jython, ibm-was, jacl

I am struggling to list active threads from a thread pool WebContainter in WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5. Can someone help me out? I am a beginner on WebSphere.

```
wsadmin.sh -lang jython -c "print AdminControl.queryNames ('name=WebContainer,process=server1,platform=dynamicproxy,node=node1,version=8.5.5.8,type=ThreadPool').splitlines()"
```

Answer (score 2):

The command you are using will actually query for thread pool configurations rather than display threads.  I think you are missing the ,* at the end of the object name, which is why it wouldn't be showing any thread pool configurations.  For example,

```
'name=WebContainer,process=server1,platform=dynamicproxy,node=node1,version=8.5.5.8,type=ThreadPool,*'
```

In order to view thread stacks of active threads, one option would be to run the following command to generate a javacore, which goes into the root folder for your profile,

```
jvm = AdminControl.queryNames('type=JVM,process=server1,*')
AdminControl.invoke(jvm, 'dumpThreads')
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I list number of active threads in those thread stacks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread Analyzer to list and investigate the thread dump. Download jca.jar : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=2245aa39-fa5c-4475-b891-14c205f7333c